# Pure CSS header items aligned horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I know there is a better/easier solution with Flexbox but I'm trying to understand the basics of CSS.
Therefore I am trying to align the header items:

- a logo image with a text on the left side - text should be vertically aligned in the middle
- a nav menu on the right aligned with the text on the left side.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.logo a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  background-color: #D5D4D4;
}
header .logo {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>

<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="" alt="brand logo (100X100 px)" class="logo">
      <span>brand name</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <a href="/">Products</a>
    <a href="/">About</a>
    <a href="/">Contact</a>
    <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
    <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
  </nav>

</header>

<div class="content">
  Page content
</div>

</body>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why are the `nav a` items vertically aligned? I apply `vertical-align: middle` only to the `header .logo` box.
2. How to I move the nav to the right? (if I use `float` then vertical-align will not work. Any clean, pure CSS solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. `nav a` is currently a child-element of `header`. So by applying `vertical-align: middle` to the `header`, it will inherently also affect `nav a`. By moving `nav` outside of `header`-tags, it will not inherent the applied CSS code.
2. To align the `nav`-items to the right without the use of Flexbox, you can use for example: `position: relative` and alter the position manually with the use of `left: XX%` of `right: XX%`. These two attributes mean: what percentage you want to move away from that direction. For example, by using `left: 100%` you are moving to affected items 100% away from the left-side of the window.

In my code snippet, i also added a solution of applying text below of an image with the use of `figure` and `figcaption` in HTML, by putting `img` and `figcaption` inside of `figure`. This way, CSS doesn't have to be applied to align the text for the logo.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.logo a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 56%;
}

header {
  background-color: #D5D4D4;
}
header .logo {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>

<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">
      <figure>
          <img src="" alt="brand logo (100X100 px)" class="logo">
          <figcaption>brand name</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
    <nav>
        <a href="/">Products</a>
        <a href="/">About</a>
        <a href="/">Contact</a>
        <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
        <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
  </nav>
<div class="content">
  Page content
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However for #1: I apply `vertical-align` to `header .logo` element which is a sibling of `header nav`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @danizgod  The inheritance of `vertical-align` is due to you having set `display: inline-block` to both those "sibling" elements as you call them.

Comment: Correct, those are not siblings. Still working on the vocabulary.

Comment: @danizgod Well no I didn't mean to correct you. You could call em sibling elements. That makes sense. Because they both share the same "parent" header box. That may even be an officially correct term usage I'm not sure! But yeah in a  I provided an answer which I think produces the output you were looking for, and the solution is TL;DR use `margin-left: X%` where you find the best X by trial and error using Chrome Dev Tools' different screen size previews tool

Answer (score 0):

User Taroti has explained your question #1 (the `vertical-align: middle` gets inherited to all other elements within the header block, and besides, wouldn't that be necessary? If you want to align the logo to be vertically centered in the header, then it will of course depend on relative positioning with all the contents of the header). For #2, moving the nav to the right, you may likely want the nav to remain in the header block, so you could instead add left margin ("margin-left") to it, thus *pushing* it if you will to the *right* (by inserting X amount of margin in between it and whatever preceding inline element, in this case the logo block (inline)).

From trial and error (using chrome dev tools) I found a value of 14% to work rather nicely across all likely ranges of screen sizes - from as small as phones to 2,000px-width+ screen. This is why it is much better to use percentage (i.e., relative value) than explicit (i.e., an explicitly defined number of px) for scaling reasons depending on the end-users screen size in pixel dimensions...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.logo a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  background-color: #D5D4D4;
}
header .logo {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 14%;
}
```

```html
<body>

<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="" alt="brand logo (100X100 px)" class="logo">
      <span>brand name</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <a href="/">Products</a>
    <a href="/">About</a>
    <a href="/">Contact</a>
    <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
    <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
  </nav>

</header>

<div class="content">
  Page content
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Of course the 14% value only looks good here in SO's snippet preview tool. When you go to "full page", 14% is not enough. So you'll have to use devtools to find what number % works best for your given web page and remember to use the feature that allows you to see the rendering of the page on various different screen sizes (iphone, tablet, small laptop, large laptop, imac, etc.)

Comment: @danizgod — does this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by

> a logo image with a text on the left side - text should be vertically aligned in the middle

because the brand logo and name actually already vertically aligned, so it's better if you provide your own brand logo. Or do you mean "horizontally" aligned?

As your second question about the `nav`, try to use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).
Here's my best attempt to answer your question:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.logo a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo img {
  width: 100px;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header {
  background-color: #D5D4D4;
}
header .logo {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.column{
  column-count:2;
}
```

```html
<body>

<header>
<div class="column">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549924231-f129b911e442?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="brand logo (100X100 px)" class="logo">
      <span>brand name</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <a href="/">Products</a>
    <a href="/">About</a>
    <a href="/">Contact</a>
    <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
    <a href="/">Free Trial</a>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>

<div class="content">
  Page content
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: No I think the OP is correct -- it's vertical alignment: middle - you are aligning the objects such that there middle points make a horizontal 0º straight line if connected; in other words, they've been aligned to have the same vertical height by center of mass (if you will), or, "middle". Whereas `horizontal alignment: middle` would cause them to overlap each other such that, vice versa, drawing a line connecting their exact centers of "mass" would be a perfect 90º _vertical_ line.

Comment: ...It is a bit confusing. And of course for the horizontal alignment there's no need to have that CSS (pretty sure it doesn't exist) because the more basic center tag or `text-align: center` achieves vertically-centered alignment (or setting margins to auto, and there's some other options too like -50% transforms in the X or Y directions). `vertical-align: middle` solves your example by transforming the column of a tag links into a straight horizontal line, which is I believe what @danizgod is trying to achieve.